# Multiple Multipart File in Spring MVC - Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have been trying to upload multiple files in my `Java Spring MVC Web` Application. I have my form as

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${rc.getContextPath()}/module/support/save-item-comment">
//other form elements
<input type="file"  name="fileUpload" multiple/>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to select and upload multiple files at a time. But multiple file uploading is not working.
Only one file can be uploaded through the code if i remove the `ajax function` and use normal `form submission.`

The thing i need to do is uploading multiple files with ajax fuction.

I use ajax for form submission and the script is:

```
$("#commentForm").submit(function(e)
{
 $("#divLoading").addClass('show');
 var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
 var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

 $.ajax(
 {
  url : formURL,
  type: "POST",
  data : postData,
  dataType : "html"
 });
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

In my controller class I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveFiles(@RequestParam("fileUpload[]") MultipartFile fileUpload[], ModelMap model) 
 { 
 //my custom logic
 }
```

I have the following bean in my root-context.xml file

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

and also this dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the error below when I try to submit the form:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/smartwcm-services] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request] with root cause
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.assertIsMultipartRequest(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:216)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(Reques
```

Comment: what  you have done is correct try adding the following two lines in ajax processData: false, 
contentType:false,

Answer (score 2):

You can do upload multiple files as follows,

HTML :

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${rc.getContextPath()}/module/support/save-item-comment">
//other form elements
<input id="file" type="file"  name="fileUpload" multiple/>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
</form>
```

jQuery :

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});

$("#commentForm").submit(function(e)
{
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#divLoading").addClass('show');

     $.ajax(
     {
        url : $(this).attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false, 
        contentType:false,
     });
});
```

Comment: If i use these HTML and jquery, i am not getting the value of the form elements including the file names in controller